# misuse field separators in awk

Tags: awk

I want to extract the number following `Pages:` in text such as

```
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          3
Encrypted:      no
```

The following awk command doesn't work well, because it has whitespaces before `3`

```
$ awk -F': ' '$1=="Pages" {print $2}' 
         3
```

while

```
awk -F'[: ]' '$1=="Pages" {print $2}'
```

produce nothing, where I think I specify two possible characters as field separator.

So how can I use awk to extract the number after  `Pages:` without preceding whitespaces? Thanks.

Comment: `grep 'Pages:' input.txt | awk '{print $2}'` will a mix of grep and awk work for you?

Comment: @sisanared That's equivalent to `awk '/Pages:/ { print $2 }' input.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to tell awk it's more than one character:

```
awk -F'[: ]+' '$1=="Pages" {print $2}'
```

Note the `+` in the regex.

Answer (score 2):

`-F'[: ]+'` is not right.  Although works in this case, it wouldn't if there were empty fields.  The right delimiter to use is `': +'`.  See the examples below

```
$ echo "a:  : b" | awk -F'[: ]+' '{print NF}'
2

$ echo "a:  : b" | awk -F': +' '{print NF}'
3
```

this should solve your problem.

```
$ awk -F': +' '/^Pages/{print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this;

```
awk -F': ' '$1=="Pages" {gsub(/ /, "", $2); print $2} '
```

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with `-F`, just:

```
$ awk '/^Pages/{print $2}' foo
3
```

**EDIT**: Oh, @BenjaminW. already suggested this in commects. Props++.